# Не работает update и computed для изменения графа

Tags: javascript, vue.js, chart.js

Мне нужно сделать так, чтобы при изменении даты она пушилась в компонент и компонент обновлялся. Я сделал это аж двумя методами, но ни один из них не работает. Один из них computed, другой - chartInstance.update(). Компьютед при изменениях тригерится, что можно проверить через консоль лог, update тоже работает без ошибок, изменения в data есть, но ничего не происходит, в чем проблема?

```html
<template>
    <div class="graph__busManag">
      <Line ref="Graph" id="Chart" :data="ChartData" :options="options" :plugins="plugins" />

    </div>
</template>

<script>

import {
  Chart as ChartJS,
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend,
} from "chart.js";
ChartJS.register(
  CategoryScale,
  LinearScale,
  PointElement,
  LineElement,
  Title,
  Tooltip,
  Legend
);
import { Line } from "vue-chartjs";

data() {
    return {
        data: ...something,
        option: ...somedata,

},
  computed: {
    ChartData() {
      return this.data; // Should update graph, but doesn't , despite the fact that it is constantly triggered
    }
  },
  mounted() {
      this.data.datasets.data = [50, 60, 70, 80, 90, 100];
      this.data = {...this.data};

      const chartInstance = this.$refs.Graph.chart

      console.log(chartInstance);
      chartInstance.update(); // not working
      chartInstance.reset(); // not w
  },
}
```

Comment: Для передачи данных в компонент нужно использовать props.

Comment: @ВикторКарев они и используются тут. Но решил это изменением :key, он вызывал реактивность.